# Chrome extension not working properly, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

here is the code I use in my Chrome extension. It's an extension that for now just intercepts the requests and prints them in the pop-up.

```
<script>
function interceptRequest(request) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode("" + request.method + " " + request.url + " " + request.headers);
  p.appendChild(text);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  document.body.append(request.url);
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(interceptRequest, null, ['blocking']);
</script>
```

When I do "inspect pop-up" by right clicking on the extension's icon I get this error from the console: `Uncaught Error: Parameter 1 is required. extensions/schema_generated_bindings.js:69`

Does anyone know what's going on? It used to work a couple of months ago, then I stopped working on this and now it doesn't work anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the second parameter of [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) (trunk of chrome extensions doc) is no more optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just checking that page but I didn't notice that parameter is not optional anymore!

Comment: @check_ca, Weird, but why is the error saying `Parameter 1 is required` instead of `Parameter 2 is required`?